# How to install theme without using user-theme extension?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04** with **Gnome Shell 3.4**. Since day one I had some random crashes mainly after reloading or during search. After a lot of research I concluded that **user-theme extension** is to blame. Only when disabled Gnome Shell runs 100% smoothly. So my question is: Is there a way to install a theme without using user-theme extension?

edit: Trying to install it via Gnome Tweak Tool without user-theme extension won't work because of [this][1].

[image]

Comment: have you tried gnome-tweak-tool ?

Comment: Can't, check the updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Extract your theme to `~/themes` or `/usr/share/themes`

I use this command for manually change theme and icon on ubuntu.

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

**Icon Pack**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'theme'
```

**Theme**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'theme'

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences 'theme'

gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/theme 'theme'
```

Change '**theme**' with your **theme name**

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

[image]

After Installation Press Alt+F2 and type 'r' to restart Gnome Shell, or just logout and login back. Open Gnome Tweak Tool to change/install shell Themes.

Comment: there is no "gnome-shell-extensions" in official repositories! Where did you find that?

Comment: of course, there is one:

packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gnome/gnome-shell-extensions

Comment: quantal is ubuntu 12.10, question was about 12.04 (precise)...